# Why is a buffer solution most effective when concentrations of salt and acid are the same?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, solutions

Why does a buffer work most effectively when the concentration of salt and acid is 1:1?

Comment: 1) Not all salts are basic. Example: sodium hydrogen sulfate (acidic salt). NaCl - salt which exerts no effect on water solution pH. 
2) Are we talking about conjugate pairs of acids/bases or just acids and bases in general?

Comment: @Dissenter: I am referring to acidic buffers e.g. ethanoic acid and sodium ethanoate

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some more information, so that we know where exactly you are stuck. (Please edit it into the question.) For example, do you care about a specific buffer?

Comment: @Martin, it is valid for acidic buffers, I guess.

Comment: @Aditya This website is no place for guessing - questions and answers should be opinion free. And I have no Idea what your comment is targeting. I asked to improve the question, as it is worded poorly, broadly and in a way, I do not want to do my own research.

Comment: @Martin I guessed that he was asking for acidic buffers and include acidic buffer in his question, not a specific buffer as you said.

Comment: @Aditya Well, these things should be clear from the questions. And that was all what I wanted to know. Btw. This is not the place to discuss how this site works - we have a chat for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Henderson-Hasselbalch-Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation):
$$\mathrm{p}\ce{H}=\mathrm{p}{K_a}+\log\frac{\left[\ce{salt}\right]}{\left[\ce{acid}\right]}$$
and buffer capacity:
$$\phi=\frac{\text{number of moles of acid/base added to 1L solution}}{\Delta\mathrm{p}\ce{H}}$$
where:
$$\Delta \mathrm{p}\ce{H} = \left|\log\frac{\left[\ce{salt}\right]}{\left[\ce{acid}\right]}\right|$$
it is minimum when $$[\ce{salt}]=[\ce{acid}]$$

Answer (score 1):

It will take an equal amount of acid or base to change the pH of the buffer the same amount. If the buffer system was established with 1:2, it would be the same as a 1:1 system after adding an equivalent of a base (or acid).

Added
Support: Just after equation 1 on [this page](http://www.science.smith.edu/departments/Biochem/Biochem_353/Buffer_Theory.html):

> Since a buffer is most effective when about half is in the acid form (Buffer H+) and half in the base form (Buffer)...
>
> The buffer concentration must be sufficient to maintain the pH within acceptable limits with the changes in proton concentration expected to occur.

Comment: Would those people who gave me a -1 explain, please.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at a titration plot of a weak acid or weak base.   When you are half way to the equivalence point the rate of change (slope) of pH vs mL titrant is near zero.  That point is when you are at 1:1 for salt:acid.

[image]